# dataGridView does not show the data

Tags: c#, sql-server

dataGridView does not show the data of the query but if it shows me the fields

```
lbnombre.Hide();
lbapellido.Hide();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AUXTECNOLOGIA\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=asistencia;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=oliver;Password=oliver14");
SqlCommand cmd;

try
{
    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select codigo_camp, grupo, nombre_n, fe_naci , edad , socio, no_carnet , recomendacion , fecha_ing , fecha_sali, sem1, sem2, sem3, sem4, sem5, sem6, sem7, alergia, dalergia, enfermedad, denfermedad, dpastilla, observaciones, nombre_em, cel_emer from cam where grupo like'%" + txtbuscar.Text + "%'", con);

    SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(ds);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

con.Close();

if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
    dataGridView1.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No se encontro nada");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query against your database manually. I suspect there are no rows.

Comment: Are you executing your query? It looks like you set up the command but never executed it.

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: Try dataGridView1.DataBind() after the line dataGridView1.DataSource=ds;